# SQL relation PHP Toolkit

Tags: soql, php-toolkit

I have the following object (hed__Course_Enrollment__c), with a relation to the Contact object:

[image]

For a given hed__Course_Enrollment__c Id, I want to show the first and last name of the contacts.

If I make the next query, I get the IDs of the contacts:

```
$query = "Select Id,hed__Contact__c FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c WHERE hed__Course_Offering__c='a042o000013Z2tiAAC'";
```

How can I get the contact's first and last name on the same call?
I've tried some querys but I get errors ...

Example 1:

```
$query = "Select h.Id,h.hed__Contact__c, c.FirstName, c.LastName FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c, Contact c h WHERE h.hed__Course_Offering__c='a042o000013Z2tiAAC'";
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [sf:MALFORMED_QUERY]
>   MALFORMED_QUERY: hed__Course_Enrollment__c, Contact c h WHERE
>   h.hed__Course_Offering__c='a042o000013Z2tiAAC' ^ ERROR at
>   Row:1:Column:96 unexpected token: 'c' in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\EUTA\portal\e\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php:789
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\EUTA\portal\e\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php(789):
>   SoapClient->__call('query', Array) #1 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\EUTA\portal\e\test.php(122):
>   SforceBaseClient->query('Select h.Id,h.h...') #2 {main} thrown in ...

Example 2:

```
$query = "Select Id,hed__Contact__c, (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact) FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c WHERE hed__Course_Offering__c='a042o000013Z2tiAAC'";
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [sf:INVALID_TYPE]
>   INVALID_TYPE: (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact) FROM
>   hed__Course_Enrollment__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:61 Didn't understand
>   relationship 'Contact' in FROM part of query call. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '**r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names. in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\EUTA\portal\e\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php:789
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\EUTA\portal\e\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php(789):
>   SoapClient->__call('query', Array) #1 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\EUTA\portal\e\test.php(122):
>   SforceBaseClient->query('Select Id,hed**...') #2 {main} thrown in ...

I'm doing something wrong in relationships ... but I don't know what it is.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `hed__Contact__r.FirstName, hed__Contact__r.LastName`? Since this is a custom field, accessing the related record fields in a lookup is *typically* done by replacing the `__c` of the field name with `__r`. [SOQL relationship documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm).

Your final query would look like:

```php
$query = "SELECT Id, hed__Contact__c, hed__Contact__r.FirstName, hed__Contact__r.LastName FROM hed__Course_Enrollment__c WHERE hed__Course_Offering__c = 'a042o000013Z2tiAAC'";
```

Comment: Replacing `__c` with `__r` is done for custom relationship fields (when querying upwards in the hierarchy, i.e. from child -> parent). Doesn't matter if the child or parent objects are standard or custom (the criteria is that it's a custom relationship field).

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I will correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had read about the __r, but I ignored how to use it correctly. With your example, the query worked and I learned the use of relationships in calls. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior since you're not mentioning the Child Relationship name in your query. For the nested queries, you need to use Child Relationship name.

For e.g. to retrieve all contacts associated with Account in a single Query would look like this:
`SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, lastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account`

here `Contacts` is a Child Relationship name. Similarly there will be also some name associated with your Contact Lookup field.

Follow below steps:

1. Click on Contact Field highlighted in your snapshot.
2. You will find
   something called as Child Relationship Name. Use that name in your
   Child Query.

Another way to find out the Child Relationship Name would be look at the Schema of `hed__Course_Enrollment__c`. Refer this [link](https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/sfdc-child-relationship-names/) for more details.